# Site Collection locked: cannot add site columns through UI

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, site-column

I found an annoying problem on a test #sp2013 server. Essentially I have been testing out some powershell code that adds site columns defined as rows in CreateSiteColumns.csv. Whilst testing and debugging I seem to have left my root site collection in 'locked state' so that the UI is now **NOT** allowing me to add, amend or delete any site columns - pressing OK does not post a request back to SharePoint so nothing in ULS.
To illustrate I created a text column via my script and attempted to amend the description

```
![Unable to add, amend or delete site columns through the UI ][1]
```

I say locked state but if only his was that simple because a quick test with PS shows it is not and also I am able to add more site columns with PS script (rows in .csv) but **NOT** via the UI. A quick test to show the locked status of my sc...

```
  $sc.WriteLocked FALSE
  $sc.IsReadLocked FALSE
  $sc.AllowUnsafeUpdates TRUE
```

Comment: please close this question by marking an answer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90193/placing-the-search-box-in-the-header/90198

Comment: Have you checked the Content Database in SQL ? I have come across a similar situation where the SQL db was left in a "locked" state after a backup. I'm not sure if it is the same as the SPSite.WriteLocked property but I would imagine it isn't.

Comment: To help troubleshoot the problem, can you determine if you are allowed to make any other sort of changes on the Site Collection / another Site Collection in the same Content Database ?

Comment: @CameronVerhelst I tested on my dev server in another site col and no problems . I have been running the code in yet another SC all day automating the creation of site columns and all good.. Took a Backup-SPSite before hand tho.

Comment: Were these SC's located in the same Content DB ?

Comment: @CameronVerhelst - all on the same content DB. I have tried other subsites within the same sc and again I cannot add a site col via the UI.  Looks like it is related to property on the sc.. I notice on this VM the memory usage is right in the ceiling of the 12GB I allocated to it.  I have seen some strange stuff happen when sp2013 starts to run out of memory  .

Comment: Since it seems isolated to the UI, it may be a permission issue ? What account is used for the web app ? Does it have permissions on the SQL Content DB ?

Comment: @CameronVerhelst . I am SP admin in every farm I touch.  It is a bit strange this issue. I often wonder that VMs hosted on a laptop are susceptible occasional issues caused  power outages and even knocks.  I will increase the RAM and failing that simply prey! Thankfully it is not the machine I need to demo to the project board and SMT.

Answer (score 1):

In past, running following command helped me. For me, it occurred when site collection backup was abruptly terminated.

Set-SPSite -Identity "{Your Site Collection URL}" -LockState "Unlock"

Comment: Ashish thanks for the advice. I did run your unlock and did an IISreset. Unfortunately issue still in play .  A bit more info: Dev Dashboard reports no post back when I click ok so nothing in ULS. Something in this site collection state is making the _layouts/15/fldnew.aspx?web=1 not work  on my dev vm. Ran script on client's dev vm and no issues ...ahhhhhhhh!!!!!